# Brownian motion, Arcsin low of zeros

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $V$ be the time of the last zero of $W(t)$ in $[0,t]$
How can I prove that $P(V>0)=1$ ?
$V =\text{sup}\{s<t: W(s)=0\}$.
$V$ has density $$f(s)=\frac {1}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{{s(t−s)}^{1/2}}, \, 0<s<t$$.

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: ... and add sone contrxt and/or thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Arcsin **law** is neither low nor high.